# Windows Explorer's "sort by file type" doesn't sort alphabetically

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Windows10 sorts by the random name that someone (Microsoft staff?) invented to describe each filetype, rather than sorting by file-type.

So, for instance, .ZIP files sort as the letter "c". (Microsoft internally calls them "Compressed (zipped) folder").

When trying to find a file of a given type - or check if that type is present in a folder - you're out of luck. The only way to find it is to go to the command prompt and use DIR or LS on "*.[extension]".

Is there a way to un-break windows Explorer and make it correctly order by file-type?

Comment: Using german Windows 10 Build 1803 here, i can't relate - sorting files by type lists them in alphabetical order on my PC.

Comment: Btw, you can edit those 'random names' under View/Options/file types. That's not a good way to solve your issue though.

Comment: It gets even worse if an editor like notepad++ is assigned to a lot of types. the column gets not just useless, but outright confusing :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have a french Windows so I may not use the correct vocabulary.*

In detailed view (with name, date, type... columns), right-click on the columns title bar, then "more", then look for "file extension". This adds a column with the file extension, and you can then sort on this.

Comment: In English Windows, the option is currently "more".

Comment: @Adam Thanks, corrected. In french it's "autres".

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by file type. Windows explorer right click "Group By". Normally is grouped by Date modified. Later, you can sort by Name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).